# Ribbon based GUI - Winforms vs WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, ribbon

For a new project, I'm writing an administrative tool as a client software. 
So far, I've only written some small winforms application with a 'old-lookin' GUI.

I'm thinking of something fresh, new looking like ribbon based design.

The questions that come into my mind are:
1) Should I prefer WPF over Winforms for a ribbon based GUI(though I've never touched WPF before)
2) Are there any recommendations for free ribbon controls? I've found out that Microsoft seems to have this ribbon license, but I still don't get it. Do they offer a full functional ribbon based control? If yes, Winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visit http://fluent.codeplex.com/ to download a free ribbon for WPF.  This ribbon has the style of the Office 2010 ribbon, and I've already used it in one of my apps.  The download also has a lot of examples on how to implement the ribbon into a WPF application.

As far as switching from WinForms to WPF, yes it's a big learning curve, but at some point you should take the dive and start learning it.  You'll be glad you did.

Comment: I've downloaded the library and the samples and experience my first wpf session. The control looks very usuable, but a thing that annoys me is the BackstageItem menu next to the tabs. (the thing mit "file" as main name) Is there a way not to show it, because I do not see any reason in using it. Haven't found a property for that :-|

Comment: Someone has figured out how to hid the BackstageButton by modifying the source code for the ribbon.  They did so by changing the BackstageButton from private to public, which allowed them to set the visibility in the code behind.  You can see the post here: 
http://fluent.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=206195

Comment: This ribbon was once cool. But the dev never responded when I ran into problems with it, the interface is way outdated and it's slow. It's slow, it flickers, it's outdated and I hate it (and I used to love it). I've completely given up on trying to get a standard - and current - ribbon. Oh, and I'm not going to pay $600 for one, either. With some effort I can make one for myself for free.